# How to Use Background Image in BootStrap .carousel-control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know how I can update the `.carousel-control` CSS to use a background image like [This Arrows](http://promap.ca/img/arrows.png) image?
I tried to update this CSS code by adding the

```css
position:absolute;
display:none;
top:50%;
margin-top:-28px;
z-index:60;
height: 50px;
width: 51px;
background-image: url(http://www.promap.ca/img/arrows.png);
/*max-height:20%;
max-width:12%;
background-size:200% 200%;*/
```

To following code but it didn't go through!

```css
.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 15px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222222;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
    -moz-border-radius: 23px;
     border-radius: 23px;
     opacity: 0.5;
     filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 }

.carousel-control.right {
    right: 15px;
    left: auto;
}

.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the arrow image to imgur or some other image hosting site?  Your link is broken.

Comment: hi I updated the link, sorry for that

Answer (score 7):

### Bootstrap Carousel Orientation

I'm also not sure **where** you want this image to go.  Where it gets put is very important

Look at this [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/70902) to see where each of the css background colors gets applied - that's where your image will go:

```css
.carousel .container {
  background-color: red;
}

.carousel-control {
  background-color: green;
}

.carousel .item {
  background-color: black;
}

.carousel-caption h1,
.carousel-caption .lead {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

### Customize Carousel Arrows

I'm guessing that you're trying to customize the arrows specifically since that's the name of your image file.

By Default the arrow image is just a `<` or `>` character by using [glyphs](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/) to specify the [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) of the anchor tag with the [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) selector as seen in the `bootstrap.css` file here:

```css
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before { content: '\2039'; }
.carousel-control .icon-next:before { content: '\203a'; }
```

You can add whatever content you'd like for left and right arrows by specifying it in the innerHtml of the arrow anchor tags

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">...</div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPWSDdP.png"/>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <img class="flipped" src="http://i.imgur.com/QPWSDdP.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

If you have a different image for the next arrow, you can use that, or you can apply a css class to it and flip it horizontally with the following css:

```css
.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
     -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
       -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
         -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
            transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

Also, add some css so the carousel image defaults don't apply to your arrows:

```css
#myCarousel a img {
    width:  20px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
}
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/HqjGZ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use background image and hide default icons

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before { content: ''; }
.carousel-control .icon-next:before { content: ''; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is broken link and there is no quotes in address.

```
background-image: url('http://www.promap.ca/img/arrows.png');
```

Comment: Thanks but I already did this the problem is bootstrap still forcing it's own control styles! beside this just display at one side(right)! the image

Answer (score 0):

.carousel-control {

```
width: 54px;
height: 54px;
background: url(images/arrow_slide_sprite.png) -10px 0 no-repeat;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -27px;
z-index: 10;
cursor: pointer;
```

}